# What is a good way to beat/stop Hugo in Street Fighter X Tekken?

Tags: street-fighter-x-tekken

I've tried numerous amounts of combinations, either my play is completely wrong to where I get stomped every game, or I'm picking super weak characters that cannot out poke or out damage him, even though that's very hard to do in the first place. So is there a way to stop his ridiculousness?  BTW, I mainly play vega, heihachi, kazuya, and lili.

Comment: Claw's reach is pretty good, you should be able to play a poke game with him.

Comment: yea, once i started to get more of Claw's combos down with Heihachi and cross-over combos, Hugo isnt as bad as he was for me. thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took me a while to learn, but i figured this one out on my own and with the help of a youtube video, In summary, down back is your friend, anti-air normals beat splash, attack to stuff his dash-ins, and jump if he tries to running grab

this video shows everything and has helped me a ton. So if you have trouble with Hugo, no more i say :D